# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset when sending HTTP request with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, connection-reset

I am trying to send a POST request with Spring Rest Template to a certain URL and getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset.

This is the actual piece of code that is executed:

```
ResponseEntity<Void> response = restOperations.exchange(eventLoggingHost, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Void.class);
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1569) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:55) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:55) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:765) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:578) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.thomsonreuters.ri.apis.research.events.repository.CobaltEventLogRepository.logEvents(CobaltEventLogRepository.java:61) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.thomsonreuters.ri.apis.research.events.repository.CobaltEventLogRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4abb4bde.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.thomsonreuters.ri.apis.research.events.repository.CobaltEventLogRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1232b88e.logEvents(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.thomsonreuters.ri.apis.research.events.EventLogAspect.processEventLog(EventLogAspect.java:137) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.thomsonreuters.ri.apis.research.events.EventLogAspect.logEventAfterReturning(EventLogAspect.java:104) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:626) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterReturningAdvice.afterReturning(AspectJAfterReturningAdvice.java:66) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.thomsonreuters.ri.apis.research.controller.ResearchController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4e911bc.getDocumentText(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.thomsonreuters.ri.apis.research.security.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:70) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

What could be the cause of this?
I have read something about closed sockets but I do not operate any of these notions at this level.

Comment: Are you using SSL? This seems to be a case, where you are not fully compliant with the expected http parameters (possibly headers)

Comment: @Kris, thanks, yes, i suppose this is worth checking. The other requests we are sending to this URL are authenticated but I may have skipped this part for this new request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there is a time out for request on the network level set by some of the Big IP services. We had to ask the maintenance engineers to increase the time out to allow for the time our request is processed.

Of course, request duration limits are set for a reason, and refactoring your code to fragment a long-executed request must be concidered rather than just increasing the timeout.